# Signing an extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

How can I sign my extension so users make sure my extension is safe and it won't steal their information? My extensions needs to access page contents, some users have no good sense of permitting an extension to do so.

Can I sign my extension using a verified sign provider, for example VeriSign?

Answer (score 3):

When you publish an extension to the Chrome Web Store, the only "proof" that users can have of your extension is given by the rating system and the comments of other users. An hypothetical user that wants to install your extension, looks at the ratings and the comments, so **make sure that your extensions has a good feedback from its users.**

By the way, **Google doesn't always look at the internal code of your extension manually**, most of the times it only performs some heuristic checks on the code. So the problem is that developers could easily include some malicious code that may not be recognized and that could harm user's privacy in their extension without any problem.

Therefore, due to the Chrome Web Store policy, **"validating" your extension is not possible at all**. Plus, using SSL servicies (like the one you mentioned) will not make any sense since that your extension's scripts are stored locally.

**What you can do is:**

- Encourage users in rating your extension and leave good feedbacks if they like it.
- Redirect users to help links in case of trouble (links like "having trouble?" in your popup and so on).
- Write a good worded description, and obviously add some images (or videos, better) to clearly show why an user may find your extension useful.
- Always be nice (implied, ahah).

Comment: -1: wrong, and not an answer to the stated question.

Comment: @Xan I answered saying that validating an extension is not possible at all.. do you know of any way to do it?

Comment: Well, not as stated, true; but extensions ARE signed, and Google DOES look at the code.

Comment: @Xan I tried it by myself, and I can tell you that google didn't ever spot my "malicious" testing extensions when published to the store... and I can't see how would they check the code in less than an hour when you update an extension... have you got some official links to prove what you're saying? If so, I'm interested :)

Comment: It's an automated heuristics system. Of course it will not catch everything, but it can flag code for manual review, that happens sometimes. Blanket statement "does not look at the code" is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your extension cannot be signed by an external provider, but it *is* signed by Chrome Web Store itself.

Every extension has an associated private key used for signing. It ensures consistent extension ID and updates. You can generate one yourself by packaging the extension as CRX (that produces a `.pem` file) and provide it when publishing on the CWS, or CWS generates it internally when you publish it (and then there's no way to extract it).

From on then, only code signed by this key (by the Web Store engine) will be recognized by Chrome as an update. Furthermore, at least on Windows only CWS-signed packages can be installed.

**This security is as strong as the developer's Google account**: if it is compromised, CWS will accept an update to your extension, which will be signed with the same key.

---

Although, as Marco correctly pointed out in his answer, the act of signing something would be just snake oil with respect to security. This signature verifies the identity of the publisher, but nothing more.

There's one more aspect - [verified sites](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34592). If your extension interacts with a site you control, you can certify this by associating your extension with the site. It will be [visible in the Web Store](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/173657).

CWS-signed packages have an additional warranty of saying "so far, we did not catch this extension breaking any rules". Google can pull the extension off Web Store, and in severe cases blacklist and remove it from all Chrome installs. So that's an additional assurance for the user.

Google runs automated heuristic checks every time you submit your extension, which *can* trigger manual review. But that's invisible to the user.

---

That said, **make sure to only ask absolute minimum permissions you need**. For instance, look into the [`activeTab` permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab). It gives full host permissions for a tab when the extension is invoked by the user, but does not result in any permission warning. This was specifically added to address concerns about blanket extension permissions.